# React - Firebase Realtime Database writing data twice

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am making a project - Gift recommendation using React. At the result page, I am trying to save the values to firebase realtime database from which I'll be fetching later for showing user their past recommendations. The problem is, firebase writes the same values twice. What is the issue? Where am I going wrong? Just to be clear, I did console log, the function runs just once, still the value gets written twice.

Code:

```
const firebasesent = () => {
    if (user !== null) {
      const username = String(user.email).split("@")[0];
      const userRef = firebase.database().ref("Users/" + username);
      const recommendation = {
        name,
        age,
        gender,
        relation,
        ocassion,
        interest1,
        interest2,
        budget,
        title,
      };
      userRef.push(recommendation);
      setSentToFirebase(true);
    }
  };
```

sentToFirebase is a state variable which I'm using to make sure that the function runs just once.

Firebase -
[image: firebaseImg]

Comment: how are you calling `firebasesent` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A single call to `userRef.push(recommendation);` will result in only one write to the database. If you see the data showing up multiple times, the most likely reason is that `firebasesent` is being called multiple times. I recommend setting a breakpoint in the method, running in a debugger, and seeing where (else) it's called from.